# If a Date is less than a date or a number is less than 1 delete the entire row

Tags: vba, excel, date-comparison

Hi I have the sheet below and I'm trying to clean it, 
[image: the table that I have is attached below]

So if the Column B is before 2018 (1/1/2018) or Column D is less than 1 the entire row should be deleted, the problem is my code is working but not full. it does not delete all the rows that meet the condition which it should, it only deletes some of the rows that meet the condition.

Also my code is

```
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow Aqs Long
    Dim PODate As Date
    Dim THDate As Date

    Worksheets("testPO").Activate
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRow, "A").Activate

    For i = 8 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, "D").Value < 1 Or Cells(i, "B") < 43101 Then
            Rows(i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp 
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: short answer: loop backwards not forwards. `For i =  LastRow to 8 Step -1`

Answer (score 3):

Work backwards or you will skip rows. If you were to delete row 9 then row 10 becomes the new row 9. On the next iteration, you examine row 10, thus skipping the original row 10 which has become row 9.

```
Dim i As Long

with Worksheets("testPO")
     For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row to 8 step -1
         If .Cells(i, "D").Value2 < 1 Or .Cells(i, "B").value2 < 43101 Then
             .Rows(i).entirerow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
         End If
     Next i
end with
```

Comment: Thank you can you tell me what is the "with" function for ?!

Comment: And why .Value2 instead of .Value ?!

Comment: a) All the .Cells and .Rows with nothing to the left belong to Worksheets("testPO"). b) It's faster for text and numbers and you had already reverted your date to a raw long..

Answer (score 0):

You want to step back upon deletion not to miss any since the loop will increment the variable i regardless of deletion:

```
If Cells(i, "D").Value < 1 Or Cells(i, "B") < 43101 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    i = i - 1 ' STEP BACK!
End If
```